# Ethernet connection connected is showing but not opening any page in browser in Ubuntu16.04 ? please help

Tags: 16.04

I am new user of Ubuntu 16.04 . In my setup wired connection1 is showing connected but any page is not opening in Mozilaa firefox or ubuntu webbrowser. So what will I do to open page on internet?

Answer (score 0):

okay, first check your ethernet card with `sudo lshw -c network`. If you see `disable` word in there it mean your ethernet card is disabled. You also need to look at `logical name : eth0`, this is important because we will fix it. Use `nano /etc/network/interface` and add

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

dont delete

```
auto lo
```

Answer (score -1):

Being a noob myself I had the same problem two days ago and I fixed it like this:
Go to Network Connections. Select the Ethernet connection you use. In the tab IPv4 Settings at Additional DNS servers add the number 8.8.8.8  Reboot and keep your fingers crossed.
This worked for me. Please let me know if it worked. Good luck!